# how handle OAuth2 token refresh in react native?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, react-native, fetch

Has any library for react native that handle token refresh? Or I need to do a schedule for refresh the token? if yes, iOS permitt the schedule execute in background? or I can check every server response if the token is valid if not refresh it?

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I faced this problem, I thought of two strategies to handle token refresh with your API:

#### 1 - Refresh on specific error from API

Your server should send a `INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR` moment at which you could make your own `refreshToken(credentials)`.

One technique that I find interesting to hook there would be to polyfill `fetch` in a similar way as in this article:
[Handling Failed HTTP Responses With fetch()](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/)

#### 2 - Refresh at app start

What I do at the moment on my app is to refresh my token at app start, regardless of the token's time to live. So unless your user keeps the app opened for a time longer than your time to live, you should not encounter any issue.

I hook at app start using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) loaded state callback.

#### refreshToken(credentials)

The refresh token function is quite simple if you use `fbsdk`:

```
import { AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

[...]

AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()
    .then((FBTokenObject) => {
        let FBToken = FBTokenObject.accessToken
        [refresh your own API token using FBToken]
     )
```

If you use an email and password strategy, you should look into [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain), to save the credentials on the device in a secure way.

#### Conclusion

I did not implement the token refresh on API error because my token's time to live is of 5 days and I think the second strategy is good enough at the moment. But I definitely would if my token's time to live was shorter than 2 days.

You can also improve performance by checking your time to live and decide, depending on the value, if you want to refresh the token or not, but, in my opinion, that's not so much of a gain.

Comment: I don't know if this is still your current solution, but how do you handling apps going to the background? iOS users will 'close' the app by pressing the home button and it is possible it stays in the background. If they open the app the next day, the token ttl is 5 days. So within one workweek, the user is logged out..?